# Jquery datepicker range selection issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i need help to figure how to select a number of data from the selected from and to date. i am using .daterangepicker

My html datepicker

```
<input type="text" name="daterange"/>
```

i have an each function that runs through my items. then i am converting from and to to a date

```
var from_date = new Date(item.from*1000);
var to_date = new Date(item.to*1000);
```

and then i am using .append to show my content, which shows as supposed.

```
$(".show_items").append(item.item_name + "<br />");
$(".show_item").append(item.item_date + "<br />");
```

Datepicker settings

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
            "startDate": date.getMonth(),
            "endDate": date.getMonth(),
        }
```

but i like to show only the data from selected range, anyone who can help?

Comment: can you provide the html, datepicker settings, example of item?

Comment: @Edwin, updated my post.

Comment: are you using this daterangepicker: http://www.daterangepicker.com/ ? And they have a demo, do you want your range to be like in the demo? e.g. 01/01/2015 1:30 PM - 01/27/2015 2:00 PM. Plus at the end they have a generator, that can help you

Comment: yes my daterangepicker is from there, but i dont know how to show the data for the selected range of date

Comment: do you have the requirements?  "Date Range Picker relies on Bootstrap, jQuery and Moment.js"

Comment: yes i have implemented it as in the demo

Comment: I don't know what you mean, i just want to show the data for the selected range

Comment: who is `date` in `date.getMonth()` and as `StartDate` and `EndDate` you need to fulfill the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, so the `getMonth()` will return something else

Comment: date.getMonth() returns the current date. and if change startDate and endDate to YYYY-MM-DD, it will say invalid date.

Comment: show us some output for the `date.getMonth()` and `StartDate` and `EndDate` should not be exactly `YYYY-MM-DD`, that's just the format. It should be something like: `2017-01-22`. And you don't need the `"` around this two.

Comment: but my startDate should always be the current day, and it returns the number of the month

Comment: then explain better your problem and offer more releveant info

Comment: What more info do you need? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144349/discussion-between-edwin-and-user993074).